# Is there any equivalent to ORACLE DBMS_SQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, cursor, dynamic-sql, equivalent

we are doing big transformation from ORACLE to POSTGRESQL and i'm trying to define all the things we should change and it seems like there is no DBMS_SQL in PostgreSQL.
I know i can do all the things with Cursors but DBMS_SQL is great for code reuse and moving cursors between different code.

Answer (score 1):

One part of `DBMS_SQL` can be replaced by dynamic cursors or dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ...'
  LOOP
    ...

DECLARE
  c1 refcursor;
  r record;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1 FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT ...'
  FOR r IN c1
  LOOP
    ...
```

Some documentation:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: ...and you can pass `refcursor` objects between functions.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response, but i'm looking for something to replace the dbms_sql procedures in the Package.
This package have procedure like : TO_REFCURSOR or TO_CURSOR_NUMBER. 
In general, dbms_sql is better for code reuse and i can't get that from pgsql cursors.